# Label a single coordinate (pgfplots)

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following plot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grmin=-5:5 -5:5]
        \addplot[mark=none] {x^2/4};
        \addplot[mark=none] {-1};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(0,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

My question is: how can I label the point `(0,1)` as "(0,1)", such that the label appears either to the right or left of the point?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the axis coordinate system to refer to actual plot coordinates and it would be great if you can include full compilable code examples as below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis y line=middle,axis x line=bottom]%[grmin=-5:5 -5:5]
        \addplot[mark=none] {x^2/4};
        \addplot[mark=none] {-1};
        \node[label={180:{(0,1)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0,1) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is almost perfect. The only change I would make is `label={180:{$(0,1)$}}` -- putting the coordinate in math mode.

Answer (score 38):

You may be looking for TikZ's *pin* option, used like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grmin=-5:5 -5:5]
        \addplot[mark=none] {x^2/4};
        \addplot[mark=none] {-1};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(0,1)} node[pin=150:{$(0,1)$}]{} ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

With PSTricks. I show you how to put a point at any location: on the curve or not on the curve.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\def\f(#1){x^2+0.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-0.5)(3,6)
    \psaxes[linecolor=gray,tickcolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-0.5)(2.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[algebraic]{-2.2}{2.2}{\f(x)}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={45,0}](0,1){F}(*1.1 {\f(x)}){A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

or

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\def\f(#1){x^2+0.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-0.5)(3,6)
    \psaxes[linecolor=gray,tickcolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-0.5)(2.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[algebraic]{-2.2}{2.2}{\f(x)}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle=-30,PointNameSep=15pt,PointName={{\scriptstyle(0,0.5)},{\scriptstyle(1,f(1))}}]
            (0,0.5){F}(*1 {\f(x)}){A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Animation

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\def\f(#1){x^2+0.5}

\def\Picture#1{%
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-0.5)(3,6)
    \psaxes[linecolor=gray,tickcolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-0.5)(2.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[algebraic]{-2.2}{2.2}{\f(x)}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-15,135},PointNameSep=20pt,PointName={{\scriptscriptstyle(0.5,f(0.5))},{\scriptscriptstyle(#1,f(#1))}}]
            (*0.5 {\f(x)}){F}(*#1 {\f(x)}){A}
        \pstLineAB[nodesep=-1,linecolor=blue]{F}{A}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=2.0+-0.1}{15}{\Picture{\n}}
\multido{\n=0.7+0.1}{13}{\Picture{\n}}
\end{document}
```

### Warning!

The point `(*1 {\f(x)}){A}` uses the following weird "RPN-algebraic" syntax

```
(*<a constant numerical value in RPN expression> {<symbolic algebraic expression in x>})
```

No "algebraic-algebraic" syntax such as

```
({<a constant numerical algebraic expression>}| {<symbolic algebraic expression in x>})
```

is available.

Comment: I did not show you the tangent line at `(0.5,f(0.5))` because it needs another trick!

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to add a single point based on a predefined function but couldn't find an appropriate answer among this question and related questions.

Therefore, for future reference, if you have your own function defined as e.g.:

```
\begin[tikzpicture][declare function={y(\x) = \x^2;}] ...
```

And you want to add a single point based on this function, you should use:

```
\addplot [only marks,samples at={5}] {y(x)} node[pin=150:{$(0,1)$}]{};
```

That's the best way to add a single point to an existing function, regardless of your `axis` setup or of other functions that have been added to the plot (you need `pgfplots` for this).

Hope this might help someone out in the future.