# How to label maximum y coordinate of data from a file. pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to label only a maximum value of `y` coordinate from data of external file.

I tried to use the features of the `calc`, but I couldn't get it; I wonder if I can use a function `maximum`.

I've seen a similar solved problem, using `pst`[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104062/label-a-single-coordinate-pgfplots), and `#1`. How can I implement in my code, for `pgfplots`.

This is the code of my graph, I am using `pgfplots` and `tikz` packages:

```
\begin{figure}[!hbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={X},
    ylabel={Y},
    xmax=50,
    xmin=0,
    ymax=.5,
    ymin=-.5,
    width=15cm,
    height=5cm,
    ]
        \addplot[blue,smooth]table{sample.table};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option; the `mark max`, `mark min` styles receive an optional argument allowing to specify the position of the node with the coordinates for the maximum (the defaults are `above` for the maximum and `below` for the minimum):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,
    /tikz/max node/.style={
        anchor=south,
    },
    /tikz/min node/.style={
        anchor=north,
        name=minimum
    },
    mark min/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamin
                \def\markopts{}%
                \coordinate (minimum);
                \node[#1] {(\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta})};%
            \else
                \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts,every node near coord/.style=green]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter,
    },
    mark min/.default={below},
    mark max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
        \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamax
            \def\markopts{}%
               \coordinate (maximum);
                \node[#1] {(\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta})};%
        \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
        \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter
    },
    mark max/.default={above},
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.table}
x y
1 0.2
10 0.1
20 0.4
30 -0.3
40 0.3
50 -0.2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={X},
    ylabel={Y},
    xmax=50,
    xmin=0,
    ymax=.5,
    ymin=-.5,
    width=15cm,
    height=5cm,
    ]
  \addplot[blue,smooth,mark max=right]table{sample.table};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used a variation of Jake's code in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55352/3954) to [How can I automatically mark local extrema with pgfplots and scatter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55349/3954)

Comment: Not sure if this should be a complete question, so I ask in a comment for the time being. Swithcing to `ymode=log` breaks the `(x,y)` label as it displays `(x,log(y))`.
What do you suggest to circumvent this ? @Jake, what is your opinion on this as original poster ?

Comment: Actually, I cheked this issue further and adding `point meta={exp(y)}` to the `axis` options corrects the output, which I find somewhat weird, but fits my need.