# TikZ's pin option: problem with positioning ordered pair

Tags: pgfplots, pstricks, tikz-pic

In a separate post, @00dani provided a nifty way of labeling points with TikZ's pin option which I'm trying to mimic.

[options for labeling single point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104062/label-a-single-coordinate-pgfplots/104066#104066)

Specifically, in a system of 1 quadratic and 1 liner equation, I want to label the 2 intersection points. The solution set for the system = (-6,3) and (-3,-3).

Presently the pointers aren't referring to the correct intersection points.

[image]

The desired graph is:

[image]

Maybe the graph is too crowded to allow for labeling the intersection points. @kissmyarmpit suggests PSTricks package to place a simple large black dot.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\def\f(#1){x^2+0.5}
```

Personally, I know very little about TiKz graphing and appreciate your most readable solution for labeling the points.

Thank you!

mwe

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      % width and height if axis, adjust to your liking
      width=7cm,
      height=6cm,
%xtick=\empty, 
% remove all ticks from x-axis
%ytick=\empty, % ditto for y-axis
      xlabel=$x$, 
      ylabel=$y$,
      axis lines=center, % default is to make a box around the axis
      domain=-10.5:5,
      samples=100]
    \addplot [red] {-2*x-9};
   \addplot [blue] {2(x+4)^2-5};
%callout for intersection point
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(-6,3)} node[pin=150:{$(-6,3)$}]{} ;
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(-3,-3)} node[pin=150:{$(-3,-3)$}]{} ;
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: On your picture, the coordinates don't seem to sit at the intersections. Are you sure that `(-6,3)` and `(-3,-3)` are the correct coordinates for the intersections?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes, those solutions are correct for the system of equations. (checked in symbolab.com) The scales for the x & y axes are needlessly different, thus distorting the point plots. Need to fix that problem, but not sure how. Thank you!

Comment: But even if the axis are scaled differently, the coordinates should still be right. You are missing a `*` in the formula. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are missing a `*` in the formula for the parabola. With `2*(x+4)^2-5`, you get the right plot. You can play with `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` to restrict the domains and scale the diagram. Also, maybe decrease the font size or reduce the number of ticks. I would probably not use pins to add the labels.

Apart from that, you can find the intersection coordinates using the `intersections` library provided by Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=7cm,
    height=6cm,
    xmin=-10,
    xmax=5,
    ymin=-10,
    ymax=20,
    domain=-10.5:2.5,
    samples=100,
    xlabel=$x$, 
    ylabel=$y$,
    axis lines=center,
    font=\scriptsize
]
    \addplot[red, name path global=line] {-2*x-9};
    \addplot[blue, name path global=curve] {2*(x+4)^2-5};

    % intersection point
    \path[name intersections={of=line and curve, name=i}];
    \fill (i-1) circle[radius=2pt] node[left] {$(-6,3)$};
    \fill (i-2) circle[radius=2pt] node[right] {$(-3,-3)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the simple, but quite elegant solution. Going forward, I will pay careful attention to including the asterisk!